# How to make a histogram using sums of several columns in SQL

Tags: sql, histogram

I often make simple count based histograms with SQL 2012 using case statements, like this:

```
SELECT
count (CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=0 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 5000000 THEN 1 END) as '5M',
count (CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=5000000 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 7500000 THEN 1 END) as '7.5M',
count (CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=7500000 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 10000000 THEN 1 END) as '10M',
count (CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>10000000 THEN 1 END) as '10M+'
FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[tableone] a inner join [DBNAME].[dbo].[tabletwo] b
on a.IDfield=b.IDfield
Where b.psc=4
```

But now I need to make a histogram of sums, and I can't figure out how to sum these values by bin, rather than count them. This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=0 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 5000000 THEN sum(a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]) END as '5M',
CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=5000000 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 7500000 THEN sum(a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]) END as '7.5M',
CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>=7500000 AND a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]< 10000000 THEN sum(a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]) END as '10M',
CASE WHEN a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]>10000000 THEN sum(a.[Val1]+a.[Val2]+a.[Val3]+a.[Val4]) END as '10M+'
FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[tableone] a inner join [DBNAME].[dbo].[tabletwo] b
on a.IDfield=b.IDfield
Where b.psc=4
```

But that throws a 8120 error - Column 'Val1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Could someone point me in a direction as to how to proceed with this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "histogram of sums"?

Comment: I now know the answer. The sum statement needs to be outside of the case statement, of the form:  SUM(Case when val1+val2+val3+val4>=0 AND val1+val2+val3+val4<5000000 then val1+val2+val3+val4 end) as '5M'